# Confusing SQL error in SELECT NULL, *, NULL, NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error, sql-injection

**The Background**
I was trying to solve the [fourth realistic mission](https://www.hackthissite.org/playlevel/4/) in hackthissite.org, and couldn't figure out exactly what SQL I should inject into the URL to retrieve the list of emails. After wasting a few hours, I gave up and looked at [a solution](http://hackthissitesoltution.wordpress.com/2012/03/08/hts-realistic-mission-4/), which gave this interesting line of code, which was to be injected after a select query:

```
UNION ALL SELECT NULL, *, NULL, NULL FROM email
```

I understand what this does and why; the hacker needs to create a query that has the same number of columns as the query it's being merged with, and shifted around the * to make sure the emails are displayed. That's not my question.

**The Question**
My question is why that code throws a syntax error in MySQL. After doing a few tests, I've found that apparently this is a valid query:

```
SELECT *, NULL, NULL, NULL FROM email
```

as this this,

```
SELECT NULL, text, NULL, NULL FROM email
```

but for some reason, this isn't:

```
SELECT NULL, *, NULL, NULL FROM email
```

and throws a syntax error " near '*, NULL, NULL FROM email' ".
I fail to understand why this is so. It seems like the query is only valid if * is the first column requested, regardless of what the other columns are. Is this a bug? Is it a feature unique to MySQL (and the mission uses a different variation of SQL)? Or am I misunderstanding this completely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [documented](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) behavior:

> Use of an unqualified * with other items in the select list may
>   produce a parse error. To avoid this problem, use a qualified
>   tbl_name.* reference

Just following the instructions.  This should parse cleanly:

```
 select NULL, email.*, NULL, NULL from email
```

Comment: Thanks for the snap response! Unfortunately I can't vote up or accept the answer yet. Is there another variant of SQL where this isn't the case (to explain why multiple solutions to the mission used this code without specifying the table name)?

Comment: You may want to check out the background in the ("won't fix: expected behaviour") [MySQL bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=26066). But basically, the SQL standard says that even `SELECT *, NULL, NULL, NULL` shouldn't technically work: *that's* a MySQL feature that's above-and-beyond the standard. `SELECT NULL, *, NULL, NULL` may work in other DB engines (I believe it works in SQL Server, but not in Oracle) but it's not standard.

Comment: @JohnQian yes not all databases will behave the same way w/ the queries in your question. In postgresql, the query you indicated was invalid in mysql would be valid.

Comment: I see. Thanks! Looks like I need to improve my googling skills.

Comment: @JohnQian . . . I know Oracle has an issue with `*` used with other columns, regardless of whether it is first or not.  I think most other databases allow it.  (I always use table aliases with `*`, so this isn't an issue I much encounter.)

Answer (score 1):

It may vary by database as to how strictly you must qualify the tables when only using one table and selecting literals in addition to all the columns on that single table.

For instance in Oracle, even this is invalid: (as is the other way around)

```
SELECT *, null from email
```

However in Postgresql, yes, it is valid (both ways)
    http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/20335/2/0

Qualifying columns normally comes into play to avoid an ambiguity error when you are using 2+ tables that have 1+ columns of the same name. Ambiguity errors are universal.

However as far as parsing, there is variation between databases. (when you are using just one table, and selecting all columns from that table, but literals in addition)